# Postfix + php translating email addresses sent to local domains to something@localhost.localdomain

Tags: php, postfix, smtp, localhost

My first question here, if I don't provide sufficient info straight away, please take it easy on me with the downvotes ;-)

I'm running a VPS hosted by afterburst.com with OpenVZ

I installed and configured successfully the following components:

```
zpanel (with apache, mysql, php5.3, postfix)
updated successfully to php5.4
running Laravel on secundary webpage (works fine)
```

Sending emails out with php as well as with MUAs works fine. Emails send from MUA to locally hosted domain also works fine.

**But here is the error:**

When I'm sending an email with php sendmail command to a locally hosted domain, the email address is translated to something@localhost.localdomain. I believe it has something to do with my DNS setup, but I tried many things and I just don't find the right answer

my hostname is

```
[user@vps ~]# hostname
vps.krause-it-consulting.com
```

here is my postfix config (postconf -n):

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
delay_warning_time = 4
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = vps.$mydomain
mydomain = krause-it-consulting.com
myhostname = vps.krause-it-consulting.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 VPS_IP
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps                                                                                                                                                      .cf
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_host_lookup = dns, native
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,        permit_mynetwor                                                                                                                                                      ks,        reject_unauth_destination,        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,        r                                                                                                                                                      eject_unknown_recipient_domain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_use_tls = no
soft_bounce = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias                                                                                                                                                      _maps.cf,                     regexp:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/virtual_regexp
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/zpanel/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_                                                                                                                                                      domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_mai                                                                                                                                                      lbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 101
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:101
```

If you need further info, please ask and I will add.

I'd like to emphasize at the end, that **only emails sent through php and sendmail command are the problem** here. Everything else works fine (so far :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering, that I was working on this issue for the past 2 weeks, after writing down the details of the problem in this question, I was finally able to fix it.

It was actually an entry I made in the hosts file that caused this issue. Perhaps I was playing around a bit too much :-)

Anyway, here is the issue line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost vps.krause-it-consulting.com krause-it-consulting.com hobbyathletes.com
```

after removing the 2 additions of my hosted domains it worked: Correct line:

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost vps.krause-it-consulting.com
```

Anyway, I hope this will help someone.